# assigning an array value to a hidden field in jquery

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

Sure I'm missing something simple here.  I'm trying to assign a value to a hidden field via jquery.  It keeps returning nothing and I've tried several things.  I have an array on a form called personemail[] and it ids and names the fields accordingly, personemail[0], personemail[1] ect and I want to extract the first email address listed and assign it to a hidden field named person_email.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var emailvalue = jQuery('#personemail[0]').val();
    jQuery('#person_email').val(emailvalue);
    });
</script>
```

I'm new to jquery so this is a bit of a mystery as to what I'm missing.  do I need to be using a .change() on the #emailperson[]?  I'm assuming I need to break into the array to grab the value but I'm unsure how.  I just can't get this piece to work.

Here is the post data

```
Array ( [person_name] => max 
        [person_email] => 
        [person_phone] => 111-1111 
        [booking_seats] => 1 
        [personname] => Array ( [0] => max ) 
        [personemail] => Array ( [0] => max@max.com ) 
        [booking_comment] => 
        [eventAction] => add_booking 
        [event_id] => 14 )
```

As you can see I get the email address into the array just fine, I just can't get it to stick to person_email

Here is a paired down version of HTML asked for, server side language is php.  The inputs are generated via a jquery clone function I've written.  Spits out a html element for each new person based on dropdown for the number of people selected:

```
<form id='rsvp-form' name='booking-form' method='post' action='<?php echo $destination ?>'>          
    <tr class="personrow">
    <th scope="row"></th><td>Name:<br><input class="required person" type="text" name="personname[0]" /><br>Email:<br><input class="required email additional" type="text" name="personemail[0]" id="personemail[0]" /></td><td class="theextra"></td>
</tr>       
<input type='hidden' name='person_email' id='person_email' />
<input type='submit' class='blkBTN' value='<?php _e('Book It!', 'dbem') ?>'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='hidden' name='eventAction' value='add_booking'/>
<input type='hidden' name='event_id' value='<?php echo $EM_Event->id; ?>'/>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: what does this array look like on the form? separate text boxes?

Comment: which language on server side??? and also show HTML code Read this : http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/  this may help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're trying to get input data on document ready - before it was submitted. In that moment there's nothing in the input field to read from. What I'd do is do it onsubmit, something like this

```
$("#rsvp-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //stop the form from submitting, you'll do it later
    var emailvalue = $("personemail\\[0\\]").val();
    $("#person_email").val(emailvalue);
    $("#rsvp-form").submit(); //you got the hidden input value, now submit the form
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/x6dPd/

edit: there was a typo in the example.

Comment: This is causing a recursion error on the .submit(); within the submit function.  It is just looping through, stopping the submit, setting the value over and over.  What would be the best method for avoiding the preventDefault after the value is set?  Perhaps a function for preventdefault that is binded to the submit that can then be unbinded once the value has been changed?

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer and start a new question related to the recursion as it is really a different issue then what I originally had.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should escape brackets in your selector (with backslashes), because brackets are special characters in jquery selectors. So you should have:

```
var emailvalue = jQuery('#personemail\\[0\\]').val();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  The special characters makes sense, however it didn't affect anything when I made the change.